# Multipart Post request in Apache Httpclient 4.5.6 not working

Tags: java, api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to upload a file to the server. The request is working fine while using Postman tool.

In Postman I have :

```
POST :https://transport-stg.transperfect.com/api/files/upload?filename=test.png&targetFolderId=2ff5ea6a-8187-4622-ab58-c7511c445ae7
```

In Header I have :

```
Content-Type = multipart/form-data
Authorixation = Bearer access_code
```

In Body I have:

```
  file = test.txt (this is file to be uploaded,able to select file location in Postman)
```

This Above is working as expected in postman tool.

**Now I wrote a below code in Java using HttpClient 4.5.6 as**

```
try {
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\lKadariya\\Desktop\\test.txt");
  String authorizationValue = "Bearer "+accessToken;
HttpEntity data = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
        .addBinaryBody("srcUploader",file,ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY,file.getName())
        .build();
  HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.post("https://transport-stg.transperfect.com/api/files/upload")
          .addHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
          .addHeader("Authorization",authorizationValue)
          .addHeader("Accept","application/json")
          .addParameter("filename","test.txt")
          .addParameter("targetFolderId","2ff5ea6a-8187-4622-ab58-c7511c445ae7")
          .setEntity(data)
          .build();
   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = response -> {
    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
    } else {
      throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
    }
  };
  String responseBody = httpClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
```

And i am not able to upload the file.
ERROr: Unable to upload file from server. 
the postman is giving the expected respone.

What could go wrong with this above Httpclient code?

**The OKhttp library is also working fine as**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
//            .addPart(
//                    Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"title\""),
//                    RequestBody.create(null, "test"))
            .addPart(
                    Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"test\""),
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_TXT, new File("test.txt")))
//            .addFormDataPart("file","file.txt",
//                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),new File("test.txt"))
//                    )
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .url("https://transport-stg.transperfect.com/api/files/upload?filename=basic.txt&targetFolderId=2ff5ea6a-8187-4622-ab58-c7511c445ae7")
            .post(requestBody)
            .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
            .build();
try {
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

What could go wrong in the HttpClient code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.post("https://transport-stg.transperfect.com/api/files/upload")
      .addHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
```

The `Content-Type` value in your code is invalid as it does not include the `boundary` parameter.

You should not meddle with `Content-Type` header at the request level and let HttpClient generate it automatically based on properties of the enclosed request entity.